# How to using telnet to test fix protocol?

Tags: protocols, telnet, fix-protocol

I am sending a `Logon` request in telnet:

```
$ telnet example.com
Trying example.com...
Connected to example.com
Escape character is '^]'.
8=FIX.4.4 9=103 35=A 49=Q142 56=XCD1 34=221 52=20170929-09:36:39 98=0 108=30 553=primexm_hgnh_uat_1_q 554=tVN84Y93THc5 10=023
```

Then I try to capture the request in Wireshark:

[image]

It alert me: `the BeginString field is missing`, what's the problem when using telnet for test fix protocol

Comment: have you replaced the [SOH] separators with spaces here or were you typing a space as a separator? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293231/fix-message-delimiter

Comment: I do not know how to type [SOH] of 0x01 in the telnet, so I replaced with space

Comment: Why the    ^.    at the beginning of the FIX message?

Comment: @TangMonk so... You knowingly sent a malformed message and get "Error/Malformed" in response and then had to ash here what the issue is??!! The hex code for SOH is 0x01 depending on your OS and telnet client you have a number of ways to send it.