# Skipping invalid message: SOH not found at end of field: 376 in gap fill response

Tags: quickfix

Gap fill request did not complete due to 'Skipping invalid message: SOH not found at end of field: 376' event. 
While reading gap fill messages from persistent file, recovery process did not read full message which caused to raise an exeception 
(8=FIX.4.29=38035=834=28292049=SOURCE52=20180208-09:54:1356=DEST128=INAP42129=CLIENT11=DFR6=011=805741214801314=015=INR17=0208201831487720=021=122=531=032=037=18020806942338=38339=640=241=CELAS805741214781744=32.6548=ELST.NS54=155=ELST.NS58=ORDER INSTRUCTION CANCELLATION ACKNOWLEDGEMENT59=060=20180208-09:54:13150=6151=383376=STOMP/2384211)
We are using MINA 1.1.0 Library. If somebody has faced same kind of problem then please help us.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293231/fix-message-delimiter) and make sure the 376=STOMP/2384211 has a SOH delimiter at the end

Comment: Thank you for reply. Complete string is present in persistent file but while reading, recovery process is reading 368 characters which is causing string truncation. Complete message length is 380 characters

Answer (score 0):

This issue we get mostly if we are reading FIX message from file.
The solution is to `trim()` the spaces and again append SOH i.e \u0001:

```
fixMessage = fixMessage.trim() + "\n0001";
```